# Native TF vs Keras TF performance comparison

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cudnn

I created the exact same network with native and backend tensorflow but after many hours of testing using number of different parameters, still couldn't figure out why keras outperforms the native tensorflow and produces better(slightly but better) results.

Does Keras implement a different weight initializer method? or performs different weight decay approach other than tf.train.inverse_time_decay?

P.s. the score difference is always like

```
Keras with Tensorflow: ~0.9850 - 0.9885 - ~45 sec. avg. training time for 1 epoch
Tensorflow Native ~0.9780 - 0.9830 - ~23 sec.
```

My environment is:

> Python 3.5.2 -Anaconda / Windows 10
>   CUDA: 8.0 with cuDNN 5.1
>   Keras 1.2.1
>   Tensorflow 0.12.1
>   Nvidia Geforce GTX 860M

and **keras.json** file:

```
{
    "image_dim_ordering": "tf", 
    "epsilon": 1e-07, 
    "floatx": "float32", 
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

and you can also copy and execute following two files

```
https://github.com/emrahyigit/deep/blob/master/keras_cnn_mnist.py
https://github.com/emrahyigit/deep/blob/master/tf_cnn_mnist.py
https://github.com/emrahyigit/deep/blob/master/mnist.py
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem was due to incorrect use of keep_prob parameter of the dropout layer as I should have fed this parameter with different values on train and test process.

Comment: Did the times remain 45s for Keras and 23s for TF? That's a pretty big difference

Comment: Hello, there is 5 sec. difference now. Native TF is faster.