# Performance comparison among Keras/Tf-slim and native Tensorflow?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, keras, tf-slim

I have a network and I am selecting the framework to implement: Keras, Tf-Slim or Tensorflow.

My question is that does the performance (accuracy) decrease when we use Keras/Tf-slim instead of native Tensorflow? I found that the time may be lower when we use Keras ([Native TF vs Keras TF performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777466/native-tf-vs-keras-tf-performance-comparison)), but how about performance?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any difference in accuracy while using keras(Tf backend)/Tf-slim in comparison to native Tf as they are just a high-level library written on top on native Tf.